# View RPM scripts with rpm --scripts -qp

Tags: linux

When I run `rpm -qlp` I get the file contents of the RPM as you can see below, but when I run `rpm --scripts -qp CBS0.0.0_10.0.i386.rpm` I get the scripts' contents, but not their filename.

My question is why can't I see the script names in the RPM contents (ie, where does the script s come from?)

```
$ rpm -qlp CS0.0.0_10.0.i386.rpm

/home/thy_diff/rt
/home/thy_diff/rt/Cerse-zip
/home/thy_diff/rt/Configure_rht.properties
/home/thy_diff/rt/UFE_Install.sh
/home/thy_diff/M_client
/home/thy_diff/M_client/Crse-CLIENT.zip
/home/thy_diff/M_client/Configure_client.properties
/home/thy_diff/M_client/UF_Install.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK scripts are part of RPM package meta-data, there are no files for scripts. The commands of scripts are written directly into spec-file just next to other meta-data like "description" or "license".

For example, see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.3/html/Deployment_Guide/satops-rpm-building.html) the `%post` section. It contains a script of a single command. I believe all other scripts are written just the same.

Answer (score 6):

Try with following command:

```
rpm  -qlp --scripts CS0.0.0_10.0.i386.rpm
```

You can see the script contents

Comment: I Know how to see the script , my qeustion was from where the script is come ? ( from which path? )

Comment: Binary rpm file contain the spec file which written into the header of the file. If you open an rpm file in a hex editor you can see the script contents close to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The `--script` flag lists the scripts. The `--triggers` flag lists the triggers function.  The `-l` flags list the installed files.  More infomation in the `man rpm`.

With following command, you can see the script contents.

```
rpm  -qp --scripts CS0.0.0_10.0.i386.rpm
```